# Jmeter load testing on a HTTP URL

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I want to perform load testing using jmeter tool on the below url, How can i achieve this,

http://thebus.in/B2C/Result.aspx?sourceId=1128&destinationId=198&doj=15/October/2014&dor=30/October/2014

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad to know that you chose Jmeter, which i love, for your load testing requirements.

Please refer to the tutorials below to get some basic idea.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4mfFSrxpl0Y

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jmeter/jmeter_build_test_plan.htm

& Ofcourse,

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/

When you come up with your own script and if it does not work as expected, Then ask your questions here to get them clarified!!